# Merged Bootstrap SCSS File

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to create a theme for bootstrap but instead of overwriting the default themes in a file, I would prefer using a bootstrap file which has all the styles of components in it.

There are some websites for bootstrap theme customization, which are exactly what I need, because it downloads theme file with every styles in it, approximately 7 thousand line. But it downloads with less extension. So there is no nesting in file.

The reason, why I need this is because later on, if I update my bootstrap file, in case they change size of h1 for example, I don't have to override it again. Even if it changes, I may not even realize.

So, do you guys know if there is a default theme file which has every style merged into one but in **SASS** format?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this website. http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/

You can download your css file from bootstrap's website and copy-paste content in .css file to css section in the website and then just click blue arrow to convert. So, your scss file will be ready.